# Measuring time lapses in kernel 2.4.37

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

My purpose is quite simple: to measure the time elapsed:

```
unsigned long start, end;

int init_module (void) {
 start = jiffies;
  printk("Hello Modules\n");
  end = jiffies;
  printk("Measuring time lapses: %lu\n", (end - start) * 1000 /HZ);
  return 0;
}
```

But this method does not work because `printk` is too short, can any one give me some suggestions? Any other options? Both C and assembly are ok. And I'm required to work under kernel 2.4.37.

Answer (score 0):

Check out printk times. This shall enable you to see the time between the calls or show time relative to a particular message. This is one of the instrumentation tool for kernel.

Provided below the related links and link for patch:
http://elinux.org/Printk_Times
http://elinux.org/images/d/d0/Instrumented_printk.patch